# watermark редактор для сайта

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, watermark

Всем привет.
В поисках реализации редактора для быстрого создания watermark'а на сайте. Пользователь должен иметь интерфейс - наложить свой логотип на фото (менять позицию, размер, прозрачность), либо напечатать текст и применить к нему те же настройки. Оптимально, чтобы редактор был визуальный.
Не ищу халявы и готовое решение (хотя может оно и существует), но буду признателен за пинок в нужном направлении - какие плагины могут пригодится и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Вот есть довольно неплохой [плагин](https://brianium.github.io/watermarkjs/) для прикрепления фото или текста как водяной знак.

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть :)

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Будут вопросы или пример - помогу напилить

Comment: В watermark.js смутило отсутствие визуализации. То есть drag&drop, resize и прочее как я понял нужно дописывать самому на jquery ui. Начал реализацию на таком примере - https://fmaz.developpez.com/proj/imgwatermark/demo.html , но на пол пути понял что этот плагин слишком "слабый". Буду благодарен за помощь в реализации

Answer (score 0):

Удивило отсутствие варианта canvas & fabricjs. А именно он и оказался быстрым и оптимальным вариантом